# Django does not allow to get/create new object: QuerySet object has no attribute get_or_create

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Python 3.2 with Django 1.6.2 on PostgreSQL
When trying to conditionally create object using get_or_create shortcut, I get `AttributeError`.

Of course, the workaround would be to catch the exception when trying to get the object and then create it. But can it be done using regular `get_or_create`?

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_or_create'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/urk/Documents/virtualenv/pycharm_python_3_3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 195, in wrapper
    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/urk/Documents/virtualenv/pycharm_python_3_3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 426, in dispatch_list
    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/urk/Documents/virtualenv/pycharm_python_3_3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 458, in dispatch
    response = method(request, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/urk/Documents/virtualenv/pycharm_python_3_3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py", line 1320, in post_list
    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))

  File "/Users/urk/Documents/xxx/app/api/userresource.py", line 51, in obj_create
    api_key, created = ApiKey.objects.get_or_create(user=rv.obj)

  File "/Users/urk/Documents/virtualenv/pycharm_python_3_3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)

AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_or_create'
```

---

**EDIT**: Code sample.
The following code from `python manage.py shell` gives the exception

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.get_or_create(username='tu')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/urk/Documents/virtualenv/pycharm_python_3_3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_or_create'
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: sure, added sample code to the question

Comment: Does that problem repeat on clean django 1.6.2 without any modules?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin, thank you for pointing me in a right direction. Recreating virtual environment solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating virtual environment as suggested by @AndreyNelubin solved the problem.